# Fabric: Local command usage

Tags: python, fabric

I want execute a command which needs sudo in local machine. So as the documentation suggests, I used the local command, but its asking me to enter the password. How can I avoid this? Is there some place where I can save my local machine password?

```
local('sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start',capture=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `visudo` command, which will allow you to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, in which you can define users, commands and password-requirements on a machine (e.g. user mlzboy does not need to enter password in order to execute `/etc/init.d/tomcat6`). Don't forget this can create a security problem.

[Sudoers manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you do not plan to share the fabfile you can use:

```
echo "password\n" | sudo -S /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

according to the sudo man page:

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
>   the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The
>   password must be followed by a newline character.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked as charm!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use sudo but on the loopback ip:

```
from fabric.api import sudo,env
env.hosts =['127.0.0.1']
sudo('aptitude search fabric')
```

No need to edit sudoers, given you have an ssh server running locally.